# Appium xpath attribute text

Tags: java, android, xpath, appium

An `Android 4.4.4` physical smart phone device is sitting on USB tether, `ADB` enabled.
Attempts are being made to automate a hybrid android application on this device via `Appium` (Java).

We are experiencing trouble reconciling elemental discovery and access behavior.

For example:

```
List<WebElement> buttons = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button[@text='Something']"));

System.out.println("Found " + buttons.size() + " buttons.");

for ( WebElement el : buttons ) {
         System.out.println(el.getAttribute("text"));
}
```

One (1) button is discovered.
The button found clearly has a "text" attribute containing "Something".
However, when trying to print the contents of the "text" attribute the result is empty; just a line return.

Additionally, when the `.click();` method is invoked, the element "clicked" is NOT the element found. In fact, according to the UI xml of the app, the element clicked isn't even an `android.widget.Button`.

Any ideas regarding what could be causing this unexpected behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that element has a text field with data in it? Open up uiautomatorviewer for android and select the element manually, and post a screenshot showing that it has data in that field

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying that you are automating a hybrid application so you have to switch context before perform any action like `sendkeys` or click or tap.
so refer to context switch tutorials and try. Basically you are on native context and for hybrid app `context` should be changed to `webview`.